# disable spaces in single line function in clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

In our code base we use the following style for single line functions:

```
int func() {return 1;}
```

However clang-format formats this as:

```
int func() { return 1; }
```

Is there a setting for clang-format to disable these spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Set `Cpp11BracedListStyle` to **true**

> If true, format braced lists as best suited for C++11 braced lists.
>
> Important differences: - No spaces inside the braced list. - No line break before the closing brace. - Indentation with the continuation indent, not with the block indent.
>
> Fundamentally, C++11 braced lists are formatted exactly like function calls would be formatted in their place. If the braced list follows a name (e.g. a type or variable name), clang-format formats as if the {} were the parentheses of a function call with that name. If there is no name, a zero-length name is assumed.

```cpp
true:                                  false:
vector<int> x{1, 2, 3, 4};     vs.     vector<int> x{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
vector<T> x{{}, {}, {}, {}};           vector<T> x{ {}, {}, {}, {} };
f(MyMap[{composite, key}]);            f(MyMap[{ composite, key }]);
new int[3]{1, 2, 3};                   new int[3]{ 1, 2, 3 };
```

[Resource](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Comment: This only applies to the space usage inside braced lists. However I would like to handle the usage of spaces inside a single line function definition. Functions do not appear to be affected by this setting.

Comment: unfortunately, I think this is cannot be done, because it is an irregular format.  I think the only way to do this is to use // clang-format off and // clang-format on to make it skip code sections.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the style our code base uses. So for now it is simpler to keep manually formatting the code base.